# Magento 2 course

Tags: magento2

Is there is a fast link to download this course:

```
https://u.magento.com/fundamentals-of-magento-2-development#.WNJJC0c2c8o
```

It is FREE access until March 31, 2017. Any body downloaded it, so can share.

Comment: What is your question/issue?

Comment: The question is so clear not issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an online course. You must register on the MagentoU platform (right side on your link). Then access on your account on the 'My MagentoU' tab.

Comment: I see, but I am ask about a fast link to full download or any body recorded it so can share.

Comment: I know. But is something I doubt anyone would share here. Check the point 6 of https://magento.com/legal/terms/magento-u
Maybe you can check on github or any other repo sites.